# Как подсвечивать ссылки при отправке сообщений?

Tags: javascript

Как в диалоге (чате) можно реализовать подсвечивание ссылок при отправке, если будет содержать `http://` или `https://`? 
Нужно, чтобы в новом окне открывалось.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG#.D0.A1.D0.BF.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BE.D0.BA_WYSIWYG-.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.B0.D0.BA.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2_HTML-.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B0

Answer (score 1):

вот работающий пример:

```js
if(!String.linkify) {
    String.prototype.linkify = function() {

        // http://, https://, ftp://
        var urlPattern = /\b(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[a-z0-9-+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[a-z0-9-+&@#\/%=~_|]/gim;

        // www. sans http:// or https://
        var pseudoUrlPattern = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;

        // Email addresses
        var emailAddressPattern = /[\w.]+@[a-zA-Z_-]+?(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+/gim;

        return this
            .replace(urlPattern, '<a href="$&">$&</a>')
            .replace(pseudoUrlPattern, '$1<a href="http://$2">$2</a>')
            .replace(emailAddressPattern, '<a href="mailto:$&">$&</a>');
    };
}


var str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum et dapibus nisi. Nam cursus lobortis quam at semper. Sed lorem sapien http://google.com, dignissim ut convallis vel, https://facebook.com porta non velit.";

console.log(str.linkify());
```

взято отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links

Comment: спасибо большое!